# How to remove a file when it's empty php?

Tags: php, file, fasta

I have multiple files. My script searches the file for the sequence name and the sequence. If it's found, the format is changed from gb to fasta and only the sequence name and sequence is kept and written back into the file. But sometimes the file doesn't contain a sequences name. In that case and I don't write anything into the file, the file is empty. This files should be removed because at the end of my script a multifasta is created from all these files.

```
# Find all gb files
$files = glob("*.gb");

foreach ($files as $filename){
    $newname = basename($filename, ".gb"). ".fasta";
    rename($filename, $newname);

    $condition = false;
    $lines = file($newname);

    foreach($lines as $line) {
        if (strstr($line, "ACCESSION") ) { 
            # Find the line containing the sequence name
            $head = str_replace("ACCESSION ","",$line);
            $final = "> " . $head;
            # check if $head contains text
            if ($head == ""){
                $condition = true;
            }
        }

        $sequence = trim($line);

        # Find the sequence and check the condition
        if (preg_match('/^\d/', $sequence) && $condition == false){ 
            $sequence = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $sequence);
            $sequence = preg_replace('/\s/',"",$sequence);
            # Store in string
            $out .= $sequence;
        } 
    }

    # Read lines into file
    $f = fopen($newname, "w");
    fwrite($f, $t);
    fclose($f);
} 

# Create multifasta
exec('for f in *fasta; do cat "$f"; echo; done > db', $return);
```

How could I best remove the file when it's empty so it wouldn't be inserted in the multifasta. I am sure it's something simple but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `filesize` command, I think:

```
if (filesize ( $filename) === 0){

    unlink ($filename);  //This will delete the file. 
    continue;  //carry on with next file
}
```

The `unlink` command will generate an error message if it can't delete the file for whatever reason. I don't know if you need to check that.

Comment: I would like to check that too. I didn't think about that.